# Book about missing sister, magical world in a chasm, and griffins

Tags: story-identification, books, childrens-novel

I’ve been desperately searching for a book I read as a child in the early 2000’s. I was born in ’92 and would’ve been somewhere between 8 and 12 when I read this book.

I’m a bit fuzzy on details but I strongly believe this book was about these people who lived near a deep chasm in the human world and a young boy’s sister goes missing after being seen near it and it’s now his duty to find her. He traverses into the chasm and finds himself in a magical world. There’s definitely a griffin (or possibly a giant eagle ?) he ends up befriending. This is where things get fuzzy; I’m pretty sure he finds out his sister is dead and he and the griffin make her a grave. I’m pretty sure he ends up entangled in a war of some sort and helps the magical creatures triumph, but I’m not 100% sure on this. I’m pretty sure the griffin/eagle flies him back up the chasm at the end.

It’s basically like a fantasy story about this boy coming of age and proving his strength and bravery. It’s been driving me nuts for years because I remember so vividly loving this book but I can’t remember the name or author or much of the details, what sticks out most in my memory is the chasm and the griffin.

Comment: The Divide by Elizabeth Kay has the chasm and the griffin and the coming of age, but not the sister. Does that look familiar at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It could be [The Wayfinder](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/628682.The_Wayfinder) by Darcy Pattison. Description from Goodreads:

> Young Winchal Eldras is a Wayfinder, one of the gifted few of G'il Rim
>   who have the ability to locate anything: a lost ring, the way home, a
>   blue dress in the marketplace, a lost child. "Finding" is a valuable
>   talent in this city that sits dangerously close to the Rift, a
>   mysterious, unexplored chasm. When the Rift claims his little sister
>   in a bizarre accident, though, Win is reduced to a Wayfinder who's
>   lost his way. But suddenly there's no time for grief--the plague has
>   come to the Heartland. And only healing water from the Well of Life,
>   on the other side of the Rift, can stop it. A prophecy commands that
>   Win must make the terrible journey to seek the Well. But no one has
>   ever braved the dangers of the Rift and returned to tell about it! To
>   make matters worse, Win suddenly has a traveling companion in Lady
>   Kala, a prized-and royally stubborn--Tazi hound with a few gifts of
>   her own. A Wayfinder with no direction can't possibly manage this
>   imperious creature from the King's kennels, much less save a
>   civilization on the edge of destruction.

[Booklist Review](https://www.darcypattison.com/books/the-wayfinder/):

> Winchal Eldras is an apprentice Wayfinder, a member of an elite group
>   of people who can locate anything or anyone. When Win’s little sister
>   slips out of the house one foggy night, he tracks her to the edge of
>   the Great Rift, where his fear of heights causes him to freeze, and
>   she falls to her death. Bereft, Win retreats into himself. Then a
>   prince of the Heartland arrives with news of a rapidly spreading
>   plague and taps Win to journey through the Rift to find the Well of
>   Life, whose waters are the only cure. With resignation, Win begins the
>   arduous trek, joined by Lady Kala, a royal gazehound with her own
>   special powers. The pair winds its way past a giant eagle, a deadly
>   crocodile, a venomous tatzelwurm, and other dangers.

Comment: OP here, I somehow ended up making an actual username and account when trying to sign back into the Iser one, but anyway... thank you so much for the responses! I do believe The Wayfinder is it! It sounds exactly right and even the cover reminds me of it, I do remember it being mostly brown colors!

Comment: @trulybrilliant Hi there! Glad you came back to give feedback - you can merge your accounts by following [the instructions there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18232/398063). This way, you'll be able to formally [accept](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) Ayshe's answer :) Please do; it will show everyone the mystery was solved, and reward both you and Ayshe with some reputation (and is the proper way to do things, eheh!)